# C++ Not Installed In Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, g++

I just installed Cygwin and can launch a bash shell from windows, do `ls`, `emacs`, `vi` , etc. However, when I do `g++` it says command not found.

I thought `g++` was installed by default in Cygwin? If that's not the case, what are the exact categories under which I can add `g++` as a package to my cygwin?

Comment: See [here](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html), in particular the section titled _General installation notes_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster simply forgot to install the required package.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you install the `Devel` packages?

I would suggest you read [this tutorial](http://www.horstmann.com/ccc/help/cygwin/install.html) to get up and running.

Comment: To get just the c++ compilers, follow [this tutorial instead](http://cs.calvin.edu/curriculum/cs/112/resources/installingEclipse/cygwin/)

Answer (score 11):

It's a good idea to just install *everything* with CygWin. When you run setup, just click on the circular icon at the top level until it reads "Full" rather then "Default" - that will install all the packages.

I've sometimes had trouble installing single packages due to dependencies but a full install is not affected by that same problem.

Disk space is cheap, your time spent trying to figure out why things don't work is not.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to conserve disk space LOL.

Comment: It should be noted that a full install it could be **up to 114 GB**, which is not negligible. I wouldn't make a full install if I was installing in an SSD.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230657/what-is-the-current-full-install-size-of-cygwin

Comment: Another possible disadvantage of a full install is, that if you run setup again to update your packages to the newest version, it might take very long.