# How to install g++ in Cygwin?

Tags: g++, cygwin, package-managers

I'm trying to compile a piece of MATLAB code containing a makefile. For the reason that I'm using Windows, I need to use Cygwin.

I have downloaded and installed Cygwin. When I tried to compile the code using `make`, there was an error that `g++` is not found.

I searched for Cygwin package manager on the net and I installed `apt-cyg` but when I search for `g++` using `apt-cyg search g++`, there is no result there!

I have updated package list (`apt-cyg update`) but finally I could not find c++ compiler for Cygwin!

How can I do it by `apt-cyg` package manager or any other way?

Comment: Assuming you originally used the cygwin setup.exe, you would return to that menu and select g++ (presumably cygwin "native") make and any other relevant packages.

Comment: @tim18 I just don't know which packages should i install that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could find the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855630/c-not-installed-in-cygwin) link.

If one uses the `MinGW` installation file again, one can add some other packages.

I installed all `Devel` packages for MinGW and followed [this](http://www.horstmann.com/ccc/help/cygwin/install.html) tutorial which helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing the package `cygport`.  It will take care of many of the dependencies you need, including g++.

Answer (score 0):

If using `apt-cyg` and looking for `g++` I would suggest to look up for the name `gcc-g++` instead of just `g++`.

In this case the command would look like:

`apt-cyg search gcc-g++` - for searching the package
or
`apt-cyg install gcc-g++` - for installing the package

**Hint**:
Names of packages can be checked on the "Select Packages" page of the Cygwin installation program. There is no need to install, sometimes it is easier just to check the name of a package and cancel the installation.

Answer (score 0):

this [link](https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/e7d54775e5ded24dfe3a9b35327977be) solved my problem
use this command to install cygwin:

setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel